# Auxiliary files in diferent folder TexMaker

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files

In TexMaker I go to Quick Build and in User I write --output-directory=files. Then when I run it the auxiliary files are properly saved in the files directory but I get `I couldn't open file name 'name.aux'`. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in `Options > Configure TexMaker > Commands` that says `Use a "build" subdirectory for output files`. Just check the box.